# Fast food restaurant simulation : How to "queue" customers?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, queue, simulation

`A link to my PasteBin:` http://pastebin.com/nzW3hZdT

> I'm in the process of simulating a fast food restaurant over three
>   hours. The three hours are divided into 18 intervals, consisting of 10
>   minutes each.
>
> Based off an arrival rate of 'r' customers per minute, 'R' is
>   established. R is the arrival rate, by probability, for all 18
>   intervals (which is more or less r/60).
>
> The purpose of this simulation is to define 'r' ourselves and see the
>   average waiting time (avgWait) of each customer in all 18 intervals.
>   Generally, the greater the 'r', the greater the 'avgWait'.

At this point in my code (pasted above), the average wait times are printing properly...for ONE customer.

Lets say it takes about 85 seconds for the first and second customer to take their orders respectively on cashier 1 and 2. In those 85 seconds, it is highly probable that more customers arrived, but since `cash1empty=FALSE` and `cash2empty=FALSE` they obviously can't get their order taken.

How can I set up this queue so then the program knows there are several others waiting to get serviced after the first two order gets serviced?

Excerpt of code:

```
if ((cash1empty==TRUE)&&(cash2empty==TRUE))
                    {
                        switch((rand()%2))
                        {
                            case 0:
                                cash1empty=FALSE;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                cash2empty=FALSE;
                                break;

                        }
                    }

                    if (cash1empty==TRUE)
                    {
                        cash1empty=FALSE;

                        switch((rand()%2))
                        {
                            case 0:
                                cash1salad=(rand()%(66-55)+55);
                                totalWait+=cash1salad;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                cash1burger=(rand()%(131-111)+111);
                                totalWait+=cash1burger;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (cash2empty=TRUE)
                    {
                        cash2empty=FALSE;

                        switch(rand()%2)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                cash2salad=(rand()%(76-65)+65);
                                totalWait+=cash2salad;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                cash2burger=(rand()%(141-121)+121);
                                totalWait+=cash2burger;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        queue++; // ???
                        /// I DON'T KNOW WHAT I'M DOING.
                    }
```

I apologize for the inconvenience but I cannot use "structures". Arrays are acceptable!

Comment: Much better prepared than yesterday's [Restaurant Simulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316990/restaurant-simulation-how-to-set-up-a-waiting-line-arrays). Even so, consider pasting the relevant piece of code in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Keep a count of the number of customers in the queue, `queuedCustomers`. Add one when each new customer arrives (at the same time you increment `totalCustomer`). Subtract one when you service the customer, i.e., when you sey `cash1empty=FALSE;` or `cash2empty=FALSE;`

Change

```
            if (customerArrive>=x)
            {

                // A customer arrived during this second!
                totalCustomer++;
```

to

```
            if (customerArrive>=x)
            {

                // A customer arrived during this second!
                totalCustomer++;
                queuedCustomers++;
            }
            if (queuedCustomers > 0)
            {
```

Addendum re: choosing a cashier...

instead of the section `if ((cash1empty==TRUE)&&(cash2empty==TRUE))`

do something like:

```
cointoss = rand()%2

if ((cash1empty==TRUE) && ((cash2empty!=TRUE) || (cointoss == 1)))
{
    // use cashier 1
} 
else if (cash2empty==TRUE)
{
    // use cashier 2
} 
else
{
    // wait
}
```

Comment: Wow, excellent alternative! Thank you.
However, by adding in `the queue--;` counters after each "FALSE" statement, the queue counter always equals 0 after each interval. Is this intended? 

Additionally, when I temporarily comment out the decrements, the # of people queued is very reasonable (say, r is defined to be 0.125 customers per minute...the queue ranges ~ 1-4 people)

A link to the current code: http://pastebin.com/zcpK0YTb

Comment: The queue will only be non-zero when both your cashiers are busy and new customers arrive, of course. Problems in your code: (1) you didn't close the `if (customerArrive>=x)` where I showed; (2) the "50/50 to decide where to go" code is setting a `cashNempty` without doing any of the work, (3) you never set `cashNempty` back to `1`.

Comment: (1) Ah right, added it in! 
(2) The reason I have this section of the code is for the program to  help decide which cashier the customer will go to in the event that both cashiers are open (this will happen 100% of the time at t=1). No orders are being taken, I'm just "closing off" one of the cashiers so the program will not always force the customer to go to cashier 1 at the start of the simulation.
(3) This is a critical element in the success of the program. It should be placed only after the customer finishes his order, but how can I tell the program this?

Comment: Lets say the first order on cashier 1 takes 60 seconds. How can I code the program to change `cash1empty==FALSE` to `cash1empty==TRUE` 60 seconds after the customer arrived at the cash.

Comment: (2) But since you never set `cashNempty` to `1` this is no good; you should combine the two tests; see my addendum; (3) you need to check `t` against the time the cashier will be ready, and set `cashNempty` to `1` when this time expires.

Comment: (2) I apologize for this question... what's the second test?

(3) Would the timer be something like this? http://pastebin.com/3PjNLxp7

Comment: (2) The first test says "use cashier 1 if empty, AND EITHER cashier 2 is busy OR  the coin toss is for cashier 1." The coin toss is only checked if both cashiers are empty. The second test is checked, if we didn't use cashier 1, to see if cashier 2 is empty. (3) You are on the right track for the timer.

Answer (score 3):

Why won't you use a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)? Using a regular array seems unjustified. With a Queue, you can use the [Dequeue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c8bzx97.aspx) method to get the first customer and remove him from the queue, and you'd add new customers with the [Enqueue()][3] method.

Why would you use anything else than a queue?

Comment: The instructor does not intend us to use structures with our level of understanding. It is beyond my knowledge of programming unfortunately